# Best function for Title capitlization?

Tags: php

Should I be using `mb_convert_case` with `MB_CASE_TITLE` or `ucwords`? Or something else? What will the differences be?

Comment: which language are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

`mb_convert_case()` is multibyte safe. `ucwords()` is not.

`mb_convert_case()` requires an extension that is not always available. `ucwords()` is always available.

So if your application will only ever use single-byte encodings then `ucwords()` gives you better portability.

But if your application might need to process multi-byte encodings then `ucwords()` will fail you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function uc_words($string){
return mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
}
```

MB means multi byte, so it can convert non-ASCII characters, ucwords can convert only ASCII.

If you use ucwords on "moj šal", you will get "Moj šal", if you use multi byte convert you will get "Moj Šal"... that's it.

Comment: how is that better than using `mb_convert_case()`?

Comment: mb_convert_case, it is using it, this is just a function so he can choose upper, lower, or title case conversion. As I stated it works with UTF-8 (multibyte) while ucwords only works with ASCII.

Comment: babonk can choose upper, lower, or title case conversion perfectly easily using `mb_convert_case()` directly. What additional functionality does your `mb_convert()` function offer? I can't see any. It's just overhead.

Comment: Absolutely nothing, I edited my post, he can write a function that will work with multibyte encodings. I always use something like this.

Comment: It converts AAAA to Aaaa. ucwords() leaves AAAA intact.